# Can a pronoun come right after a noun

Tags: pronouns

So I have chanced upon this sentence

> These workers are not worth our paying **them** anymore.

I am really puzzled by this kind of structure. Should it be **our payment** instead ? If *paying* is somehow a noun, then why using *them* ?

Comment: *Paying* is not a noun here, it is a verb. And *them* is the indirect object of the verb. If you want to shorten the sentence and it's already understood who might be doing the paying, then you could go with "the workers aren't worth paying any more".

Comment: "paying" is a gerund here, so it's in a strange category as it is a noun that acts like a verb. Do you understand? These weird gremlins are also categorized as "verbals" or "verbids".

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, "paying" is not exactly a noun, but it's not exactly a verb either (roughly speaking). In this sentence it's a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) — a part of speech combining properties of a verb and of a noun. Quoting the Wikipedia article:

> A gerund is a verb form that functions as a noun.

As a verb form, it can accept an indirect object "them". At the same time, as a noun-like part of speech, it can follow a possessive pronoun "our".

Comment: So by what you mean, "My walking in the park" is grammatically correct, although it makes no logical sense ?

Comment: @randomtrekker: Yes, "my walking in the park" is a grammatically correct clause, but it's not a full sentence. It makes just as much sense as "my book" -- a noun phrase, but not a sentence. There will be more meaning to it if you put it in a sentence. For example: "During my walking in the park I witnessed a robbery."